# Are answers about beta versions of Ubuntu accepted?

Tags: discussion, answers

I know what to do about **questions** with problems in *beta/alpha/development* Ubuntu versions, but I'd never though about **answers**.

I came across this though while reviewing [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/347273/62483).

What do you think that should be done with this sort of *answers*?
Are them allowed no matter the case?
Where the difference remain?

Comment: I say that that is a workaround to a bug... he should report it.

Comment: I'm almost certain there is a question about this already.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the answer fixes a problem, great.

It's not that we hate alpha/beta.  It's that:
a) We can't possibly field all the bug reports.
b) It changes too rapidly to maintain a real Q/A for beta specifically.
c) It really hurts our answer rate/percentage.
d) It burns out users that are capable of answering those questions.
e) Possible other reasons.

In most of the above cases, answers for beta are good and don't violate the rules at all.

In all cases, people that generally want to be helpful should be encouraged not silenced.  As long as the answer isn't something like "They refused this simple patch to fix their stupid issue" it should be fine to leave answers for beta alone or even up-vote them if they're accurate.

EDIT:  Addendum - We definitely should NOT have answers that advocate upgrading to alpha-beta to fix an issue.